# Linux/Apache 2.4.3 MPM event error scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a server used for shared hosting running Linux/Apache 2.4.3 event MPM

Apache is reporting
"error scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers" in the error log every second.

I don't know what this means and I am at a loss as I usually find plenty of information on apache errors reading the documentation or on google but not this time.

All websites seem to be online, but occasionally someone reports me he/she can't access his/her website and I am starting to wonder if this error has anything to do with it.

EDIT:

Before writing this question, I tried to increase ServerLimit and MaxClients and then httpd -k graceful but the issue didn't go away. I now tried httpd -k stop and httpd and the error is gone.

It looks to me as though httpd -k graceful was not good enough but still can't grasp why.

Comment: When modifying the Apache MPM configuration, it is better to do a full stop and start. Add the configuration for the MPM (prefork, worker or event) you are using to the question. "apachectl -V" will tell you which one is in use on your server.